# Is it possible to stop completed reminders from still reminding me on other devices?

Tags: icloud, calendar, reminders

I've got a Mac Mini, a MacBook Air and an iPhone. I set a scheduled reminder on one device and it reminds me on all devices, great! The thing is, after having been reminded on my Mac Mini, for example, and clicked Complete, my iPhone and MacBook Air will still remind me. The same applies for calendar reminders too.

Is it possible to stop *completed* reminders from still reminding me on other devices?

Comment: Are they all signed-in with the same Apple ID?

Comment: I believe this is a bug - you have to dismiss it on all devices in my experience too, unfortunately

Comment: @fsb yes that's why they appear on all the devices

Comment: @EzekielElin maybe that's the reason but since I don't have that problem, and I'm signed in with the same Apple ID, I wanted to make sure from the OP.

Comment: I’m signed in on the same Apple ID on all devices.

Comment: I think there's a slight delay for the servers to update and your devices to periodically sync to the server. Are you allowing time for this?

Comment: Like I said - I see the same issue. It occurs when the notification has appeared on both devices. Marking one complete never clears the notification on the other device.

Comment: @JBallin I sometimes don't use my MacBook Air for days and when I log in I get every single reminder I've missed, very tedious. I think my best option is to just switch off syncing and rely on my phone/watch.

Comment: That makes sense that you'd see those reminders initially, because your Air hasn't had a chance to sync - so it's using what it has stored locally from the last fetch. I see that kind of stuff too but I just clear out the notifications and possibly open the relevant apps so that they sync. You can also consider turning off notifications for those app while maintaining the sync - that way you can still read/update the latest on your Air without getting bothered.

Comment: It doesn’t make sense at all. If UX was the focus it would sync before it served stale reminders. What it has locally should be be checked otherwise what’s the point in a cloud service?

Comment: I agree Apple could improve the syncing, a minor annoyance for me as well. I notice it mainly with messages not being marked as read. That’s feedback you’d have to give them directly, I’m just trying to explain how I believe it works in its current state.